# vim - Prefix number to 3 letter combination bdw

Tags: vim

I am learning Vim and I have come across this situation.

```
Hello, World!
           -
```

I want to delete `Hello, World`. If I entered <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> (go to beginning of word, delete word) three times then it would delete it. However, I want to type <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>to save typing, but it goes three words back and deletes that word, leaving me with `, World!`. Is there any way to prefix a number to a three letter command or is there another command I should be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to prefix a number to a three letter command or is there another command I should be looking at?

The problem is that it's not a 3-letter command, it's two seperate commands.

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> will do what you want, but it does require the extra 3.

EDIT:  Years later... I notice a small optimization to this case <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>. The only small issue is that you need that leading w to correct the cursor position.

Answer (score 3):

Move the cursor under `!`, then press

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> (delete back until first `H`)

<kbd>F</kbd>=<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

> `Hello, World!`

Go to the beginning of line (by pressing <kbd>0</kbd>) and type the following:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>`!`

Explanation:

<kbd>d</kbd> delete

<kbd>t</kbd> until the character before `!` in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Move the cursor under the !  (<kbd>$</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd>)

Then write <kbd>d0</kbd> (which means delete til beginning of line)

You can also do <kbd>0</kbd> (go to beginning of line) then <kbd>dt!</kbd> (delete until next `!`)